# compatibility centos 7.9 and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, centos, compatibility

I'm searching about postgresql compatibilty with centos 7.9.

if we look at this [PostgreSQL Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.delphix.com/docs536/delphix-administration/postgresql-environments-and-data-sources/postgresql-support-and-requirements/postgresql-compatibility-matrix)
does that mean that there's no compatibility between PostgreSQL 9.x and centos after 7.6 version ( 7.7 or 7.8 or 7.9 )?

and is PostgreSQL use packages in centos os ? so is there a compatibility matrix between these packages  and PostgreSQL ?

Comment: Postgres 9.x is no longer supported anyway

Comment: CentOS future is rocky. RedHat dropped it and its future is uncertain. I would get away from it.

Answer (score 0):

In the link that you post they are talking about the compatibility  between the plugin and PostgreSQL/CentOS

> Unsupported PostgreSQL Versions and Features
>
> PostgreSQL versions below 9.4 i.e (9.2, 9.3) are NOT supported by the
> plugin.
>
> It is not possible to access the staging server with PostgreSQL 9.4
> and PostgreSQL 9.5 versions.

Comment: So, what about compatibility between postgresql and centos

Comment: If you are using the official repo on centos 7.X  the latest version availab le is 9.2. Based on this [link](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/) . If you want to install later version you have to download the rpm and install it by yourself